# 'user' field keeps getting nulled

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create something where the current logged user can create 'posts'. Here's my codes:

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Posts
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
```

`forms.py`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        labels = {
            'content': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
        fields = '__all__'
        # exclude = ('user',)
```

`views.py`

```
def my_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile_info = request.user.userprofileinfo

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = forms.PostForm(data=request.POST)

        if post.is_valid():
            post.save(commit=False)
            post.user = user

            post.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('td_app:index'))
        else:
            print(post.errors)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('td_app:my_profile'))
    else:
        form = forms.PostForm

        data = {
            'user': user,
            'profile_info': profile_info,
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'td_app/my_profile.html', context=data)
```

I have declared the 'user' field to be 'hidden' since we don't want users pretending to be someone else when they post - the 'user' field should automatically register the current logged user. However it keeps giving me this error:
`<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

When I do this instead:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        labels = {
            'content': ''
        }
        # widgets = {
        #     'user': forms.HiddenInput()
        # }
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',)
```

It will now give me a null error:
`The above exception (null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint`

I'm relatively new to Django so forgive my naiveness.
How can fix this? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However it keeps giving me this error: `This field is required.`

that's because you have the `user` field in form (even though it's a hidden field), but it does not have any value (and I think all fields are mandatory by default), so the form validation complaining about missing field value is expected.

My suggestions would be to remove the `user` field from form (using `exclude = ('user',)` you have there commented out already), and then inject the `request.user` before calling `save()`. Setting `post.user = user` doesn't do anything (or at least not the thing you think it does), because your variable `post` isn't actually an instance of `Post` model, but instance of `PostForm`. The instance of model which will be saved is available in `post.instance`. So what you want to do is this

```
form = forms.PostForm(data=request.POST)
form.instance.user = request.user
form.save()
```

As for the reason why your form doesn't have any value in the `user` field is because you dont fill the form with any data. To achieve that you have to use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) parameter of the form:

```
else:
    # now the form will contain `user` value
    form = forms.PostForm(initial={'user': user})
```

but I rather would recommend hiding the `user` field in form anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only for the answer but for the explanation as well! :)